# Error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP, How fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I encouter following error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> ```
> An error occurred at line: 8 in the jsp file: /student/StudentError.jsp
> The method println6(String) is undefined for the type PrintStream
> 5:              <p><b>Stack trace:</b></p>
> 6:              <%
> 7:                      Exception exp = (Exception)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
> 8:                      System.out.println6(exp.getMessage()+"<br/>");
> 9:                      StackTraceElement [] elements = exp.getStackTrace();
> 10:                     for(int i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
> 11:                             System.out.println(elements[i].toString()+"<br/>");
>
>
> Stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
>         at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
>         at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
>         at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:801)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:200)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:75)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1217)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:801)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1126)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1060)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:509)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:288)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:240)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:539)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

**Here file JavaClazzWeb-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd ">
        <!-- <bean id="xsltViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver"> 
            <property name="order" value="1"/> <property name="viewClass" value ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltView"/> 
            <property name="sourceKey" value="data"/> <property name="suffix" value=".xsl"/> 
            <property name="prefix" value="/xsl/"/> </bean> <bean id="studentDAO" class="edu.java.spring.dao.StudentDAO"> 
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> <property name ="insertSQL" 
            value="insert into student(name,age) values(?,?)"/> </bean> <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"> 
            <property name="targetObject"> <ref bean="studentDAO" /> </property> <property 
            name="targetMethod"> <value>createTableIfNotExist</value> </property> <property 
            name="arguments"> <list> <value>student</value> <value>create table student( 
            id bigint primary key generated always as identity(start with 1,increment 
            by 1), name varchar(1000), age integer ) </value> </list> </property> </bean> -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring.controller" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:resources location="/avatar/" mapping="/avatar/**" />

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="3" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/student/" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="multipartResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
            <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="xsltViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="2" />
            <property name="basename" value="views" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="1" />
            <property name="viewClass"
                value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
            <property name="definitions">
                <list>
                    <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/definitions.xml</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="studentDao" class="edu.java.spring.dao.impl.StudentHibernateDaoImpl" />
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>

            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.java.spring.model" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="url"
                value="jdbc:derby:D:\PROJECTSPRING\studentdb;create=true" />
            <property name="username" value="" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
            <property name="exceptionMappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="java.lang.Exception">StudentError</prop>
                </props>
            </property>

        </bean>
        <bean id="studentMapper" class="edu.java.spring.model.StudentMapper" />
    </beans>
```

Here file StudentController

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/student/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//  public String addStudent(@Valid Student student,ModelMap model){
//      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
//      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
//      return "StudentView";
//  }
    @RequestMapping(value="/student/form",method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public ModelAndView student(){
        return new ModelAndView("StudentForm", "command", new Student());
    }
    @Autowired
    public StudentHibernateDaoImpl studentDAO;
```

**Here file Class StudentHibernateDaoImpl**

```
public class StudentHibernateDaoImpl implements StudentDAO {
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void insert(Student student) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> listStudents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = sessionFactory.getObject().openSession();
        Query query = (Query) session.createQuery("from Student");
        try {
            return (List<Student>)query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            // TODO: handle finally clause
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Here file Class StudentDao

```
public interface StudentDAO {
    public void shutdown();
    public void insert(Student student);
    public List<Student> listStudents();
    public Student loadStudent(int id);
    public void update(Student student);
    public void delete(Integer id);
    public List<Student> searchStudent(String name);


}
```

**Here file POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.java.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springDAT-MVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springDAT-MVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>








  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springDAT-MVC</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Here file Student

```
package edu.java.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
@Entity
@Table(name = "student",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="Id")})
public class Student {
//  @NotBlank
//  @Size(min=2,max=100,message ="Age value is invalid")
    private String name;


    private int id;
//  @Range(min=1,max=150)


private int age;
     @XmlAttribute
      @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="id", unique=true,nullable =false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlElement
    @Column(name = "Name",nullable = false,length = 200)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    @Column(name = "age",nullable = false)
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add this annotation to your @Repository StudentHibernateDaoImpl class, so that your bean spring container will scan this class. And change your component scan to your DAO class as well.<context:component-scan base-package="edu.java.spring" />

Comment: @PraveenKumar you can help me

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question**

1. From effective Spring 2.5.x versions, have a concept of [stereotyped Annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/package-summary.html) you have to mark to your classes with these annotations to make it eligible for component scanning.
2. In your case you have mark your DAOImpl class with @Repository annotation like this given below.

   > @Repository
   >   public class StudentHibernateDaoImpl implements StudentDAO {
3. Change your component scan tag as

> ```
> <context:component-scan
>  base-package="edu.java.spring.controller,yourPackage.StudentHibernateDaoImpl"/>                                                                       >
> ```

4. Here is an [example](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-annotations-component/) which will resolve your issue.

Comment: this way is right, but it's not enough. i have a new error:`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentHibernateDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean edu.java.spring.dao.impl.StudentHibernateDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;`

Comment: i have added "hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar", but still encouter similar error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentHibernateDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean edu.java.spring.dao.impl.StudentHibernateDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition;`

Comment: @DatPham, Can you post your POM.xml or JAR files which is present in your WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: i have add Pom.xml on my post

Comment: @DatPham, I notice some inconsistency in versions of SpringFramework, Please change your Spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE and Spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE, also ensure you have maintained consistent version of HIbernate also, Hibernate 4.3.8 core final depends on org.hibernate.common » hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.final and org.hibernate.javax.persistence » hibernate-jpa-2.1-api. Please ensure these jar files have been included as a dependency.

Comment: @DatPham, And in your code StudentHibernateDaoImpl.java please remove  **@Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;** which is causing the issue, because you have already set this in your xml file.

Comment: ,i have tried, i think it's not solution. should add `@Autowired to find LocalSessionFactoryBean in file xml`

Comment: @DatPham, Since you added in LocalSessionFactoryBean in your JavaClazzWeb-servlet.xml file, there is not need to autowire in your code into StudentHibernateDAOImpl.java class. Can you please post your full stack trace?

Comment: i have up file Student.class and full stack trace on my post.

Comment: i thank @Praveen , i have fixed it, add `@Id in my Student.class`.

Comment: Cool, as per question,  @autowiring issue, I have placed the solution as answer. Please accept my answer for future knowledge base :-)

Comment: @Praven Kumar, when i have run jetty successly, but i brower `http://localhost:8080/student/list`, I encouter a new error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:`

Comment: Might be your JSP issue, please check you have applied proper imports